# How do I do a diagonal-arrow keyboard shortcut?

Tags: keyboard, mac, shortcut-menu

Occasionally, you see a keyboard shortcut for something in an app's menus that shows a diagonal-pointing arrow (one that points 45, 135, 225, or 315 degrees) rather than your standard up, right, down, or left arrow keys. Here's a screenshot of what I'm talking about:

[image: Screenshot showing a sample diagonal arrow]

How do I accomplish that key chord?

Answer (score 40, accepted):

I suggest you to open your *Keyboard Visualizer* (by clicking on the flag that is near the clock in the menu bar).

(on recent macOS versions, this feature is named *Keyboard Viewer*)

This will make appear a window with a keyboard representation.

If you press the <kbd>fn</kbd> key, you'll see that the <kbd>←</kbd> will become a <kbd>↖︎</kbd> (Home key) in this window while <kbd>→</kbd> will become <kbd>↘︎</kbd> (End key).

That's it: just press the <kbd>fn</kbd>+<kbd>←</kbd> or <kbd>fn</kbd>+<kbd>→</kbd> to obtain the diagonal-arrow.

Comment: While I haven't used the keyboard visualizer, pressing `fn`+`←` does accomplish the command. Thanks.

Comment: **UPDATE** In modern versions of macOS (macOS ver. 13 Ventura as of writing this) it is called ["Keyboard Viewer"](https://support.apple.com/guide/mac-help/use-the-keyboard-viewer-on-mac-mchlp1015/mac).

Answer (score 7):

These are the home and end keys on OS X.

- On full keyboards, there are keys designated to home and end.
- On notebooks you can press home by pressing fn+left and end by pressing fn+right.

  > #### Additional key behaviors
  >
  > - The Numlock key has been removed on Late 2007 and later Mac notebooks.
  > - Home key functionality is performed by pressing Fn (Function) and Left Arrow key.
  > - End key functionality is performed by pressing Fn and Right Arrow key.
  > - Page Up key functionality is performed by pressing Fn and Up Arrow key.
  > - Page Down key functionality is performed by pressing Fn and Down Arrow key.

  <sup>Source: http://support.apple.com/kb/ht3164</sup>

Answer (score 1):

As of macOS 10.13.5, the "keyboard and emoji viewers" are accessible from a checkmark in:

System Preferences -> Settings -> Keyboard -> Keyboard (tab)

Then check the box next to "Show keyboard and emoji viewers in menu bar"

[image: Keyboard System Preferences]

(screenshot from macOS 10.13.5)

Answer (score 0):

Following up on @lauhub's answer, you enable the system's Keyboard Viewer in the Keyboard system preferences. In the "Input Sources" tab, check "Show input menu in menu bar." (In older versions of OSX, this is International system preferences' "Input Menu" tab.) The newly-enabled menubar menu includes "Show Keyboard Viewer."